# PHP singleton pattern - question about extends

Tags: php, singleton

Just a quick question. I understand that Singleton patterns can be extended and that inheritance is applied. I was just wondering if I called a base class and then a extended class is there additional overhead than if I just called the extended class by itself?

Comment: What does this have to do with a singleton?

Comment: Nothing other than that that's the angle OP is coming at it from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you're talking about is something like

```
class BaseSingleton {
    public function DoSomething() {
    }
}

class ExtendedSingleton extends BaseSingleton {
    public function DoSomething() {
        parent::DoSomething();
    }
}
```

then yes, there is overhead in the call being forwarded from the child class's `DoSomething()` to the parent class's.  If `ExtendedSingleton` does not redefine `DoSomething()`, though, there is no additional overhead.

Comment: You mean the line "public function DoSomething() {parent::DoSomething();}" is redefining the DoSomething() function in the BaseSingleton class?